# Is it possible to add/set headers in Icecast XSL files?

Tags: xslt, icecast

I have a json.xsl file which needs an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

My attempt at getting this working was by adding

```
<http-headers>
    <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
</http-headers>
```

to the top of the "json.xsl" file, hoping you wouldn't have to set this globally, but despite it still parsing properly, it doesn't add the header.

Is this simply not possible, or am I using the wrong tags (or putting the tags in the wrong location?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Icecast 2.4.2, it allows you to configure arbitrary headers. Both globally and per "mount". You can define a "mount" for a XSLT file to apply e.g. headers or authentication.

Also Icecast >2.4.1 has a working JSON API. (In 2.4.0 there are problems and it is NOT recommended to use!)

https://wiki.xiph.org/Icecast_Server/Installing_latest_version_(official_Xiph_repositories)